# stuck in nested table in a word document using Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

```
while (doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Bookmarks.Exists(@"\EndOfDoc") == false)
                {
                    //Skiping table content and proceeding with only paragraphs  
                    if (doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdWithInTable) == false)
                    {
                        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.EndKey(ref wdLine, ref wdExtend);
                        currLine = doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text;
                        temp = currLine;
                        // Move to next line after assigning to temp
                        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveDown(ref wdLine, ref wdCountOne, ref wdMove);
                        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.HomeKey(ref wdLine, ref wdMove);
                        //<Match some text on paragraph>
                            if (temp.StartsWith(searchValue))
                            {
                                resultValue = temp;
                                 break;
                            }  
                    }
                    else //If its a table
                    {
                        // navigate to next line
                        while (doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdWithInTable) == true)
                        {
                            if (doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Bookmarks.Exists(@"\EndOfDoc"))
                            break;
                            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveDown(ref wdLine, ref wdCountOne, ref wdMove);
                            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.HomeKey(ref wdLine, ref wdMove);
                        }
                            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveDown(ref wdLine, ref wdCountOne, ref wdMove);
                            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.HomeKey(ref wdLine, ref wdMove);
                        }
                }
```

I am new to C# and I am trying to read through word documents using Interop, While doing so, I am stuck in a nested table present in the document and the control keeps on looping around this table indefinitely. The problem here seems to be that It is not able to come out of the table and hence not able to find "\EndOfDoc " bookmark. Any help on getting out of table and proceeding with further processing is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should happen with content in the table? You don't seem to have any processing of the content? Do you want to skip tables?

Comment: Yes. I want to skip the whole table and move on to the next paragraph

Comment: Did my answer help you? You're new to StackOverflow so I feel I should mention that for other users of the site it's important that you mark "the answer" and upvote useful contributions, both in comments and in Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Range for the Table object, then collapse that Range to its end-point to get beyond the table This would replace the second while loop:

```
 Word.Range rngTable = null;
 object oCollapseEnd = WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
 if (doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdWithinTable) == true)
 {
    rngTable = doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Tables[1].Range;
    rngTable.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
    rng.Select();
  }
```

Note 1: I'm typing this off the top of my head because I'm not at a machine where I can test it, so watch out for minor syntax errors...

Note 2: You might want to try declaring a Selection object, rather than working with doc.ActiveWindow.... as it will be easier to read, easier to type and probably execute more efficiently:

```
 Word.Selection sel = doc.ActiveWindow.Selection
```

Note 3: Normally, you shouldn't work with Selection at all, but with Ranges. However, given that you want to work line-by-line you really haven't much choice. If, however, these lines are actually paragraphs (carriage return at the end) then there is a much more efficient and less verbose way to code what you have.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me.